# How can I convert geopoint data of mongoDB to Elasticsearch 7.x in this case?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, geolocation, geopoints, geohashing

I want to convert geo data of mongodb to elasticsearch 7.x in realtime.
I just know that should to use `logstash-input-mongodb` plugin of `logstash`.

Please, let me know how can I make `logstash.conf` refer to below.

I have a mongodb data like :

(some fields were encrypted. using `GibberishAES.size(256)` with custom string key.)

```
{
"id" : "john",
"age" : 26,
"geo" : "Cdzv5OoMXFw89do5NUorGkiRzAtnIpIw66kg=", // "57.233, 129.11"
"address" : "I6LoxOQPRPF7h4SLQo2g=" // "Rovert Hall"
}
```

To elasticsearch data like :

```
{
"id" : "john",
"age" : 26,
"geo" : "drm3bt", // geohash data of "57.233, 129.11"
"address" : "Rovert Hall"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it as made mongodb `oplog` sender.

read mongodb oplog with encoding data and then send it with decoding to `logstash`.

if someone find solution, you can find it in below :

> Here : https://github.com/gnokoheat/oplog